# SQL: How to store data about multiple users on multiple platforms?

Tags: sql

I'm working on a Discord bot project in python, which can store data about multiple users on multiple servers.

Problem is, users should not share the same data between servers.

To do so, I'm using the SQLite3 lib from Python3, and I'm currently wondering about how to store the data efficiently

I wondered if it's possible to store data as such :

```
Guild | Guild value | Users             |
      |             | UID | User Values |
```

Is that possible ? Or is there a more efficient way to store my data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the situation correctly, you have users with unique identities but who are on multiple servers (or guilds).

This sounds like a something you can do with three tables.

First, a user table containing user_id as a primary key and then whatever fields you want.

Second, a guild/server table with guild_id as primary key and then whatever fields you want.

Third, a user-guild table that holds user_id and guild_id values as foreign keys (which link to the first two tables) to show relations between users and guilds (many-to-many relationship). This table could also hold fields that are specific to a given user-guild pair (based on your comment that "users should not share the same data between servers").